# Java - Editar Registro do Windows 7

Tags: java

Estou tendo dificuldades em alterar essa chave do registro do windows com nome de "start" de "1" para "4".

Utilizando uma Bíblioteca.

```
            // Leitura de Chave
        String opcao;
        String productName = Advapi32Util.registryGetStringValue(
        WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\cdrom", "Autorun");
        opcao = (productName);

        if (opcao.equals("1")) {
            Advapi32Util.registrySetStringValue(WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\cdrom", "Autorun", "4");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opção modo: " + opcao + ". USBs Desativados! ", "Aviso!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        } else if (opcao.equals("4")) {
            Advapi32Util.registrySetStringValue(WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\cdrom", "Autorun", "1");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opção modo: " + opcao + ". USBs Ativados! ", "Aviso!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
```

Comment: Dificuldade é uma palavra bem ampla nesse contexto, explicite-nos mais qual a sua dúvida e o que queres fazer.

Comment: Já testou rodando o programa com permissões de administrador? Apenas administradores podem fazer alterações dentro de HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE